# Why do questions get less upvoted than answers?

Tags: feature-request

Most of the time in Puzzling, people get the fun after seeing the answer so they upvote the answers. Generally question get upvoted less than answers.

So I think when an answer gets upvoted, say by 3 upvotes, the question should get upvoted by one vote.

Comment: I do the opposite, I upvote questions first as they mark the inception of good (yet-to-come) time in solving a puzzle.

Comment: Related to this [question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-is-our-reason-for-wanting-bounties-on-questions) and this [answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4886/20274)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether [questions deserve more *rep*](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-is-our-reason-for-wanting-bounties-on-questions) or not aside, as a general rule I think *voting* on questions and answers are actually reasonably even.

Here's a [graph showing **question score** (x-axis) vs **highest answer score** (y-axis)](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/513760#graph). There's obviously a lot of variance, but to my eye the trend line is roughly linear and 1 to 1.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37788/what-is-the-snake-trying-to-tell-us might be my question , i just wanted to show how answers in puzzle create more impulse than the question , where the writer of question would have already thought it would create that impulse.so some credit has to go to the person who created the question if it is a original one ...

Comment: I don't think your data supports the statement. The *visual* impression is good for **very high number votes** (both Q&A), but the real "meat" of the OP's question is in the <20 votes situations, which are far more frequent. There, the relation is much less 1:1. Having said that, I don't mind it. I think voting for Q and A **should** be different. because one judges the quality of the puzzle, the other ranks "good answers". However, I do think that given reputation should be re-balanced for Puzzling.

Comment: It looks like it's a 0.79:1 ratio Q:A, but it's not that great a correlation: 0.44 R.

Comment: @BmyGuest ,will agree with you .....

Answer (score 7):

There have been many times in the past where I've upvoted a reasonable answer to a question, but for one reason or another also downvoted the question. This can happen for many reasons. However, it would defeat the purpose of a downvote on the question if an upvote on a reasonable answer *also* carried an automatic upvote of the question.

It's important to bear in mind a couple things:

- An upvote on an answer isn't a statement about the quality of the question - it's a statement about the quality of the answer. The two, while frequently related, are not actually directly linked; it's possible to write a good answer to a poor question, or the other way around.

  The freedom to separately judge the quality of content is one of the integral aspects of Stack Exchange's voting system, and is one of the features provided that works very, very well for us here, setting us apart from many puzzle sites across the 'net.
- One upvote carries +5 reputation - a downvote carries -2 reputation. In other words, every upvote counts for two and a half downvotes.
- Generally, changes to the reputation system need to be thoroughly motivated. Reputation is integral enough that *all* changes will have unforeseeable consequences, and we're weighing the cost of those consequences against the benefit derived from the change.

  One of the key parts of this is that you can't assume anything about what someone's vote means, beyond "quality content." In other words, the assumption that upvoting an answer *means* the question was interesting is unreliable.

You may, however, be interested in [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/can-we-get-10-reputation-for-upvotes-on-questions), which discusses higher reward for upvotes on questions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That first point is too good. Also to note that there are [questions like this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37776/knights-on-a-torus/37777#37777) which get more upvotes because of the idea they carry (in simple words originality).

Comment: It's worth noting that there's even a [special badge](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) for providing a highly-voted answer to a much downvoted question.