# Is it on topic to ask for the creation of a puzzle with some specific parameters?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I would like to ask the following question:

> I'm trying to make maths interesting for my six year old son.
> Therefore I have bought a box, within which I can put prizes. I will
> lock the box with a 4 digit combination lock. All I need now, are some
> mathematics relate puzzles that must be solved to find the
> combination. So my question is, can you suggest a suitable puzzle for
> the box?

But is it on topic for the site?

Comment: Please see [Would puzzle-construction challenge questions be off-topic for this site?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/would-puzzle-construction-challenge-questions-be-off-topic-for-this-site). The TL;DR is that the [puzzle-creation] tag is for asking about the *process* of puzzle creation (e.g. "how do I prevent a Sudoku from being too easy"), not for people to create a puzzle for you. There would be no single correct/best answer. Instead it'd invite a big list of recommendations.

Comment: However, feel free to ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)!